# How can I create a branch locally which track a remote branch

Tags: git

I read 'http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/13/list-remote-branches.html'
. I am using git 1.6.3.3. My question is how can I check out a local branch which track a remote branch 'origin/2-2-stable'? In other words, when I push, I will push to 'origin/2-2-stable' instead of 'master'?

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git branch -a
* master
  origin/1-2-stable
  origin/2-0-stable
  origin/2-1-stable
  origin/2-2-stable
  origin/3-0-unstable
  origin/HEAD
  origin/master

$ git branch -r
  origin/1-2-stable
  origin/2-0-stable
  origin/2-1-stable
  origin/2-2-stable
  origin/3-0-unstable
  origin/HEAD
  origin/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *quick way to do this* would be `git checkout 2-2-stable`.

This creates a local branch `2-2-stable` which tracks the remote branch `origin/2-2-stable`, and checks out this branch.

The long way would be to use `git branch 2-2-stable origin/2-2-stable` (and doing the checkout separately). If `origin/2-2-stable` is not a remote branch, you would have to give the `-t` option to `git branch`.

Comment: How can I double check if my branch is tracking the remote branch correctly? I have done 'git branch -a', it does not show which remote branch I am tracking.

Comment: Look at `git config -l`, it should show it in the `branch.*` keys.